# What is the best way to improve the performance of iterating through a std::vector?

Tags: c++, for-loop

When i looked at the typical way of iterating through a vector...

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); i++)
{
   doSomething(my_vector[i]);
}
```

...i thought it might be faster this way...

```
size_t i = 0, size = my_vector.size();

for (i; i < size; i++)
{
   doSomething(my_vector[i]);
   //I know, the size of the vector must not be changed here
}
```

...because size() will be called only once and not every loop.

Maybe somebody is able to make this clear for me, Thanks!

P.S. Should i use std::vector::iterator?

(sry for bad english)

Comment: Normally, the compiler would optimize the first version. Thus, there would be no difference.

Comment: Did you try simply testing which is faster?

Comment: Actually, the function will not be called at all if your compiler can be regarded as useable: It will be inlined and optimized away.

Comment: If somebody is still interested: The version without size() call in the for loop performed 1,26 times better in a little profiling test with valgrind....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might well be faster, but since you're using C++, an alternative might be to use an iterator instead:

```
// declare it to be some appropriate type of iterator
for (it = my_vector.begin(); it != my_vector.end(); ++it)
    doSomething(*it);
```

You will want to be careful here, though, that you're not inadvertently constructing temporary copies of each item in `my_vector`.

If you're using C++11, another option is to use range-for:

```
for (const auto &thing : my_vector)
    doSomething(thing);
```

Note that the use of `const` and `&` mean that we avoid copying each item in `my_vector`.

Comment: thanks, too! But if i use vectot::iterator, there will be a call to end() every loop, or?

Comment: No offence, but the OP asks which version of two versions she/he illustrated is faster. How this answer addresses the OP's question. Plus, in modern compilers there's effectively no difference in iterating a vector with iterators and with indices.

Comment: @40two: The OP says he isn't using C++11, so it's quite possible it's not a "modern compiler."

Comment: @user3685236: yes, there will be a call to `end()` every loop, at least in theory.  In practice, that could be optimized out as a *loop invariant* by the compiler or could be a computationally inexpensive operation.  The usual performance killer in such loops is not the call to `end()` but in unnecessary construction/destruction of temporary copies of each item.  Profiling the code is the sure way to tell.

Comment: The problem is, that i want it to compile well on "old" or "uncommon" compilers without relying only on optimization, although i'm using the newest GCC/G++ at the moment...

Comment: Surely, you understand that modern doesn't mean lastest ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify the elements, you can try this:

```
for (const auto &elem : my_vector)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but i won`t be using C++11

Comment: No offence, but how this answers the OP's question.